# connect 4 minimax algorithm: one for loop

Tags: python, algorithm, artificial-intelligence

I'm trying to write the minimax algorithm in python with one `for` loop (yes I know wikipedia says the min and max players are often treated separately), and I'm using the variable `turn` to keep track of whether the `min` or `max` player is currently exploring options. I think, however, that at present the code wrongly evaluates for `X` when it is the `O` player's turn and `O` when it is the `X` player's turn.

Here's the source (p12) : http://web.cs.wpi.edu/~rich/courses/imgd4000-d10/lectures/E-MiniMax.pdf

Things you might be wondering about:

1. `b` is a list of lists; `0` denotes an available space
2. `evaluate` is used both for checking for a victory (by default) as well as for scoring the board for a particular player (we look for places where the value of a cell on the board ).
3. `makeMove` returns the row of the column the piece is placed in (used for subsequent removal)

Any help would be very much appreciated. Please let me know if anything is unclear.

```
def minMax(b, turn, depth=0):

    player, piece  = None, None
    best,   move   = None, -1

    if turn % 2 == 0 : # even player is max player
        player, piece = 'max', 'X'
        best, move    = -1000, -1
    else :             
        player, piece = 'min', 'O'
        best, move    = 1000, -1

    if boardFull(b) or depth == MAX_DEPTH:
        return evaluate(b, False, piece)

    for col in range(N_COLS):
        if possibleMove(b, col) :

            row   = makeMove(b, col, piece)
            turn += 1  # now the other player's turn
            score = minMax(b, turn, depth+1)

            if player == 'max':
                if score > best:
                    best, move = score, col
            else:
                if score < best:
                    best, move = score, col

            reset(b, row, col)

    return move
```

@seaotternerd. Yes I was wondering about that. But I'm not sure that is the problem. Here is one printout. As you can see, `X` has been dropped in the fourth column by AI but is evaluating from the min player's perspective (it counts 2 `O` units in the far right column).

[image: Board wrongly evaluating?]

Here's what the evaluate function determines, depending on piece:

```
if piece == 'O':
    return best * -25
return best * 25
```

Comment: Could you clarify what these columns are? Also, is this after changing the turn update? And finally, could you post the rest of the evaluation function? (for instance, where does 'best' come from?)

Comment: @seaotternerd: You can view the complete code [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/83a7q1snvijchxh/SO_C4.py) (around 200 lines).

I think this will answer all your questions, but please let me know if you have more.

Answer (score 0):

You are incrementing `turn` every time that you find a possible move and not undoing it. As a result, when control returns to a given minMax call, `turn` is 1 greater than it was before. Then, the next time your program finds a possible move, it increments `turn` again. This will cause the next call to minMax to select the wrong player as the current one. Overall, I believe this will result in the board getting evaluated for the wrong player approximately half the time. You can fix this by adding 1 to `turn` in the recursive call to minMax(), rather than by changing the value stored in the variables:

```
        row   = makeMove(b, col, piece)
        score = minMax(b, turn+1, depth+1)
```

EDIT: Digging deeper into your code, I'm finding a number of additional problems:

1. `MAX_DEPTH` is set to 1. This will not allow the ai to see its own next move, instead forcing it to make decisions solely based on getting in the way of the other player.
2. `minMax()` returns the score if it has reached `MAX_DEPTH` or a win condition, but otherwise it returns a move. This breaks propagation of the score back up the recursion tree.
3. This is not critical, but it's something to keep in mind: your board evaluation function only takes into account how long a given player's longest string is, ignoring how the other player is doing and any other factors that may make one placement better than another. This mostly just means that your AI won't be very "smart."
4. EDIT 2: A big part of the problem with the way that you're keeping track of min and max is in your evaluation function. You check to see if each piece has won. You are then basing the score of that board off of who the current player is, but the point of having a min player and a max player is that you don't need to know who the current player is to evaluate the board. If max has won, the score is infinity. If min has won, the score is -infinity.
    def evaluate(b, piece):

   ```
   if evaluate_aux(b, True, 'X'):
      return 100000

   if evaluate_aux(b, True, 'O'):
      return -100000

   return evaluate_aux(b, False, piece)
   ```
5. In general, I think there is a lot that you could do to make your code cleaner and easier to read, which would make it a lot easier to detect errors. For instance, if you are saying that "X" is always max and "Y" is always min, then you don't need to bother keeping track of both player and piece. Additionally, having evaluate_aux sometimes return a boolean and sometimes return an int is confusing. You could just have it count the number of each piece in a row, for instance, with contiguous "X"s counting positive and contiguous "O"s counting negative and sum the scores; an evaluation function isn't supposed to be from one player's perspective or the other. Obviously you would still need to have a check for win conditions in there. This would also address point 3.

It's possible that there are more problems, but like I said, this code is not particularly easy to wade through. If you fix the things that I've already found and clean it up, I can take another look.

Comment: @hovaflow - okay, I edited my answer. I think this includes a lot of the problems, but there might be more that are masked by these.

Comment: I disagree with the statement "you don't have to know who the current player is to evaluate the board." If the current player is `O` and `X` has just won, wouldn't we need to report that to `O`? 

I'm writing code for tic-tac-toe now and hopefully this will be easier to debug/offer suggestions. I'll try to address some of your points about verbosity, too. The evaluation function will be much cleaner.

Comment: You're completely right that O needs to know if X just won. But, classically, the way that you communicate that to O is to assign the board a score of infinity (or 10000, in this implementation). This is also how you communicate to X that X just won. Conversely, a board score of -infinity (or -10000) indicates to both players that O just won. The idea is to come up with a board score that indicates which player the current board set-up favors, and by how much. Higher scores mean max (X, in this case) is doing well, lower scores mean min (O) is doing well.

Comment: Yes I agree. I'll link you code by 6 ET tonight for tic-tac-toe. I came across a new algorithm, negamax, that I think is more in the spirit of what I'm trying to do. The code is less than 100 lines and I would really appreciate a look, if you have time. Thank you; you've cleared up a lot of confusion.

Comment: If the logic is correct, adapting to a more complex Connect 4 game shouldn't be too hard (all that would need to be changed is evaluation, check win...). Again, I would really appreciate a look: https://www.dropbox.com/s/jzel60jn76a80xl/TTT.py

Comment: I'm sorry - I don't have any experience with negamax. Based on what I was able to read quickly, I don't see any glaring problems with your approach. And you're right that it should extrapolate fairly well. My only suggestion would be to try to trace through exactly what is happening at each point in time to see where specifically it's going wrong.